# NullPointerException on ImageIcon that exists

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jframe, imageicon

I'm working on a basic game with a few friends. Trying to load and imageIcon image from the class tile throws a nullPointerException even though the png exists on file.

Here is the board class that is calling the file

```
public Board(String name){
    super("Monopoly");
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    die = new Dice();
    andy = new Human(name, 1200, new ImageIcon("assets/img/redBullet.png"));
    blank = new ImageIcon("assets/img/white.png");
    paid = false;
    tile1 = new Tile(1,"normal", 100, new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("assets/img/redBullet.png")));
```

Then it goes on to call

```
        tile1.getImage().paintIcon(board, getGraphics(),((int)andy.getPos().getX()), ((int)andy.getPos().getY()));
```

The tile constructor is as follows

```
public Tile(int Position, String Type, int Price, ImageIcon img)
{
    position = Position;
    type = Type;
    price = Price;
    image = img;
}
```

Any help it's a nullPointerException on the tile1.getImage() line

Edit:

Stack trace

Line 246 is the call method

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.paintIcon(ImageIcon.java:413)
at Game.Board.<init>(Board.java:264)
at Game.MainMenu$1.actionPerformed(MainMenu.java:81)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:713)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:711)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:710)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: That line has several method calls that can result in a NPE. try and spread them over a few lines with temporary variables, it'll be easier to spot the actual error.

Comment: Try `"/assets/img/redBullet.png"` . not relative to the package of the Board class. Also mind that the path is case-sensitive (inside a jar or on Linux). Check that the jar (= zuip file( contains that path. A stack trace would be nice.

Comment: I split the line up and it wasn't getting my getGraphics().toString() but that might have been me! I tried changing it to just "/assets/img/redBullet.png" didn't work!